# Question seemingly deleted. Lack of transparency?

Tags: support

I posted a question, I'm pretty sure it successfully posted, and then it disappeared (on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)  I searched google about disappeared questions found a long thread, saying questions can get deleted "for a good reason" and there's no way to view deleted questions with a rep of under 10k.  If a question is deleted, shouldn't the reason be recorded and stated?  Otherwise, I have no idea if the question was actually deleted.  Or was there a glitch in the system?  Did my browser not successfully submit it?  I am left with a feeling of lack of clarity and transparency.

Comment: aside from 10k users the post owner can see it too. a question can be automatically deleted if it has a low score after i think 30 days. you might be about to find it by going to the question's list in your profile and going to the bottom of the list where there is a link saying "deleted recent questions"

Comment: Look at [your questions tab](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/12594/otto?tab=questions). Do you see anything there?

Comment: No, it says "You have not asked any questions".  So maybe a glitch...

Comment: There's currently a bug in that page that prevents users seeing their list of deleted recent questions if they have no undeleted questions to show. Your question can be found here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341323/good-programming-environment-for-teaching-learning-js

Comment: A workaround, if your deleted question isn't appearing in your questions tab, is to check through your browser history. When a question is deleted it isn't obliterated, it's just marked as deleted. The OP as well as any users with sufficient privileges can still see it. The URL doesn't change. So if you visited your own question and it's still in your history, you can find it that way, too. But yeah except for the bug animuson just described that you unfortunately ran into, normally your deleted question would still appear on that page, at least for a certain amount of time (60 days I think?).